# SQL Select to spread row data to columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this select

```
SELECT  
        products.prod_name, SUM(beg_inv - end_inv)  AS inv,
        MONTH(task_date) MONTH
    FROM    performances 
        INNER JOIN tasks 
        ON performances.task_id = tasks.task_id
        INNER JOIN people
        ON people.person_id = tasks.emp_id
        INNER JOIN products
        ON performances.prod_id = products.prod_id
    WHERE   YEAR(task_date) = '2013'
    GROUP BY performances.prod_id, MONTH(task_date)
    ORDER BY MONTH(task_date), prod_name
```

and its out put is:

```
Prod name   inv month
Product 1   5   3
Product 1   10  5
```

I would want to spread it like this:

```
Product Name    January February    March   April   May June    July    August  September   October November    December
Product 1                               5           10
```

Is it possible without having to do a Pivot and just in select?

Comment: this the kind of thing i think a report tool would be more appropriate. you're wasting db resources to format presentation given that SQL was not built for that IMO.

Comment: @Sid: Only choice is Pivoting.

Comment: I am using PHP/Code Igniter/MySQL. I am really not sure how to use a reporting tool but if that is possible using that, do you have any idea what could suit to what I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the pivot in SQL like this:

```
SELECT products.prod_name,
       SUM(case when MONTH(task_date) = 1 then beg_inv - end_inv end)  AS January,
       SUM(case when MONTH(task_date) = 2 then beg_inv - end_inv end)  AS February,
       SUM(case when MONTH(task_date) = 3 then beg_inv - end_inv end)  AS March,
       . . .  
FROM    performances 
        INNER JOIN tasks 
        ON performances.task_id = tasks.task_id
        INNER JOIN people
        ON people.person_id = tasks.emp_id
        INNER JOIN products
        ON performances.prod_id = products.prod_id
WHERE   YEAR(task_date) = 2013
GROUP BY products.prod_name,
ORDER BY products.prod_name,;
```

Note that this also requires small changes to the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried this way and it seems ok at first, If I dont add MONTH(task_date) to Group By, the results are not correct, if I do add them, I split the Products having multiple Months

Comment: @Sid . . . You have to explain better what "results are not correct" means.  I'm pretty sure this query does what you intend.